# Why do I get "illegal use of pointer" when constructing a command line for system()?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code, hoping to change the color of the console window:

```
char r[16] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};
while(true) {
  cout <<"ololol";
  system("color "<<r[rand()%15]<<r[rand()%15]);
}
```

I get this error message from the compiler:

> Error E2087 seizure.cpp 11: Illegal use of pointer in function main()

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: i get this: Error E2087 seizure.cpp 11: Illegal use of pointer in function main()

Comment: It's when you create a small, complete, otherwise-correct C++ program and post it to ideone.com, with the "Run Code" checkbox turned on, and give us the URL so that we can see for ourselves what the problem is with your approach. The process of creating this testcase -- and all the stripping-down that goes with it -- is called debugging, and is vital before you post any question here.

Comment: See, those compilation errors are what you need to fix before that is a valid testcase. C++ headers don't end in `.h`.

Comment: Borland? Allir, I fear you might be using a development environment that's older than you are. Find something newer. GCC and Microsoft both offer free compilers. Even Borland C++ 5.5 was free back in 2000, and it supported the standard header names, so you must be using something very, very old.

Comment: @Allir: But ideone does not run Borland.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
std::ostringstream cmd;
cmd << "color " << r[rand()%15]<<r[rand()%15];
system(cmd.str().c_str());
```

You use the ostringstream for formatting. `.str()` gets you a `std::string`. `.c_str()` gets you a c-style string, which is what `system` requires.

For testing, try this instead:

```
std::ostringstream cmd;
cmd << "color " << r[rand()%15]<<r[rand()%15];
// system(cmd.str().c_str());
std::cout << cmd.str() << "\n";
```

That way, you'll be able to see if your string formatting worked accidentally blowing up your monitor.

Comment: how would i do this? where would i put this?

Comment: If you want this to happen a zillion times, put it inside your `while` loop. If you want it to happen once, put it inside your `main` function. From your question, I had assumed that you had already written those parts of your program, and just needed help with the string formatting.